# Pandas DataFrame - Getting first two rows in each group

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe of below structure. Its grouped and sorted by first two columns. I want to have first two rows in each group. How i can get that?

[image]

Comment: I downvoted because: question is not reproducible, contains numerical data as image, does not show any attempt of solving the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `groupby_head`:

```
>>> df
               open
AVN  20210929   119
     20210928   110
     20210927   120
PSMC 20210929   270
     20210928   265
     20210927   260


>>> df.groupby(level=0).head(2)
               open
AVN  20210929   119
     20210928   110
PSMC 20210929   270
     20210928   265
```